# Find particular record from an array in Mongodb

Tags: mongodb

Hi i am new to Mongodb...
I have a collection i.e.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b5437c1e8c56c92098f684f"),
    "name" : "Mongo",
    "list" : [
        {
            "id" : 1,
            "author" : "biswa"
        },
        {
            "id" : 2,
            "author" : "jack",
            "editions" : {
                "version" : 8
                "version" : 9
            }
        },
        {
            "id" : 3,
            "author" : "jony"
        }
    ]
}
```

Now i want find record whose `id` is `2` of list array..i tried `db.doc.find({name : "Mongo"},{"list.id" : 2}).pretty()` 
but it shows some different output i.e.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b5437c1e8c56c92098f684f"),
    "list" : [
        {
            "id" : 1
        },
        {
            "id" : 2
        },
        {
            "id" : 3
        }
    ]
}
```

what will be the `find` command for this...

Comment: ***but it shows some erroneous output*** what's that?

Comment: I mean different output which is not as per my requirement....

Comment: Then please post the output you expect from above collection

Comment: `{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b5437c1e8c56c92098f684f"),
    "name" : "Mongo",
    "list" : [
        {
            "id" : 2,
            "author" : "jack",
            "editions" : {
                "version" : 8
                "version" : 9
            }
        }    ]
}`  

Like this....

Comment: use `$elemMatch` projection https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50973336/mongodb-query-subdocuments-by-field-valeu/50973913#50973913

Comment: Thanks @Anthony I will try....